# Getting nullpointerexception onChildClick

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

Trying to get text value of child in expandableListView.

Getting a nullpointerexception in the onchildclick event.

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(358): at tournament.tracker.pkg.ExpList$5.onChildClick(ExpList.java:124)
```

Line 124 is the `adapter.getChild` line.

I'm trying to pass the string value of the child that is clicked to another activity.

```
expList.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener()
  {

    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
        ExpandableListAdapter adapter = getExpandableListAdapter();
        gametype = adapter.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString();
        //---------------------
        Intent pullt = new Intent(ExpList.this, JsonActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("gametype", gametype);
        pullt.putExtras(bundle);
        pullt.putExtra("gametype", gametype);

        startActivity(pullt);
        //---------------------
        return false;
    }

  });
```

Anyone know why this is not working? Please help if possible

*EDIT*

Here's the adapter:

```
public class ExpAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

      private Context myContext;
      public ExpAdapter(Context context) {
       myContext = context;
      }

      @Override
      public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
       return null;
      }

      // Other code - not relevant
     }
```

Comment: How exactly does the exception look like? (aka: stacktrace plz!)

Comment: Where are you getting a NullPointerException?

Comment: On a quick guess only `adapter` would be a possible candidate. So `getExpandableListAdapter()` returns `null`. Have you set an adapter?

Comment: 05-24 17:42:42.587: E/AndroidRuntime(358):  at tournament.tracker.pkg.ExpList$5.onChildClick(ExpList.java:124)

Comment: so what is line 124? Also .toString() on a child view will give you a weird result :-/

Comment: Either your adapter is null, or the child view the adapter is returning is null. Only possibilities

Comment: EDITED onChildClick Function now works as desired. This will be a valuable question/answer which anyone trying to do what I did can now have access too.

Comment: @user1411823 do not edit your question and change it to an answer, tidy up your question and less people will downvote it. If you have the answer wait the 3 days and answer your own question and mark it answered. If someone else provided you with the answer in a comment ask them to write it as an answer an you will mark it as answered. That is how you will restore your reputation.

Comment: I have edited your question and the answer. I hope you learn from this example. Please mark @Sam's answer as correct (by clicking the arrow below the up/down rep next to the answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return null;
}
```

This function will **always** return null. Trying to access null in any way (like using `toString()`) will create a Null Pointer Exception, you must implement this function to return actual data.

A fix may possibly be:

```
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return ExpList.arrChildelements[groupPosition][childPosition];;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you give me a quick example of how to do so? If you have time. Thanks for your time aswell

Comment: You haven't provided much context so this is a blind guess, but try `return ExpList.arrChildelements[groupPosition][childPosition];`

Comment: Thank you Sam you provided Valuable knowledge. See edit at bottom of description for the working onChildClick function. If you wouldnt mind could you bump my rep up. This will be a valuable question/answer for anyone looking to do the same thing. I couldn't find any explanation on how to do this now many people will be able to.

Comment: The fix was simplt to set the string like so. gametype = ExpList.arrChildelements[groupPosition][childPosition];